# git commands with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess

Please help.
I run a git command and want to read output.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'fetch'],
                 env=os.environ,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 cwd="path to repo",
                 universal_newlines=True)

outs, errs = p.communicate()
rcode = p.returncode
```

I got output:
 
**rcode** *0*
 
**outs** *""* 
 
**errs** *From bitbucket.org:myname/project0\n * [new branch]      fetch_out  -> program/fetch_out\n*

The command has been finished correct. 
**Why message has been send to stderr ? I expect on stdout.**

Comment: See https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sismo/issues/70 git fetch returns in err not out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+stderr